# copy --from=builder failed in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment

My `Dockerfile.prod` is

```
FROM python:3.10.11 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -y update \
        && apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib \
                libpq-dev \
                gcc \
                python3-dev \
                musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.10.11

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

RUN addgroup app
RUN useradd -g app app

ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/server/AA/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME
COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

and the error ...

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref "/usr/src/app/server/AA/requirements.txt": not found
```

I checked `requirements.txt` is in the right path, but the error occurred.

I tried...

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/server/AA/requirements.txt .
COPY --from=builder ./requirements.txt .
COPY --from=builder ./AA/requirements.txt .
```

It had same error.

Comment: In the first stage the `WORKDIR` is `/usr/src/app/server` (no `AA` subdirectory), and you `COPY requirements.txt .` into the current directory, so it will be in that absolute path for `COPY --from` in the second stage.

Comment: (In the second stage, you don't need to make a variable for the current directory or to manually create it.  I'd set `WORKDIR /app`, `COPY ... ./` into the current directory, and remove the `mkdir` and `chown` commands.  Not directly related to the issue but it would remove about a third of the lines from the final stage.)

Comment: Sorry I can't understand about second comment. Do you mind telling me more specific? @DavidMaze

Comment: If you run `WORKDIR /app`, then that directory is the current directory `.` for all purposes inside the image.  You can `COPY --from=builder ... ./` to copy into the current directory, for example.  `WORKDIR` also creates the directory.  That means you don't need to set a separate `ENV` variable with the directory name, and you don't need to `RUN mkdir` on it.  For most purposes it's also usually right to leave the directory owned by root even if you're running as a non-root user.